# Shiny DT package filter warning

Tags: r, filter, datatable, shiny, dt

I'm using the DT package to make an app in Shiny. Thanks to other advices its working well, but when I include the filter argument (which is by default 'none'), I get the next message:

*Warning in run(timeoutMs) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
Warning in run(timeoutMs) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf*

I get this message even before I upload a file, so I think perhaps the problem is in the read.table arguments, but I can't find the solution. This is the code:

**Ui.r**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(DT)

shinyUI(fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("Journal"),

 fileInput("FileInput", "Choose file 1"),


 DT::dataTableOutput("table"))
```

**server.r**

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  datasetInput <- reactive({
    infile <- input$FileInput
    if(is.null(infile))
      return(NULL)
    read.table(infile$datapath, header = TRUE, sep="")

  })

  output$table = DT::renderDataTable(
    datasetInput(),
    filter='top',
    extensions = c('TableTools','ColVis'), 
    options = list(dom = 'TC<"clear">ftir',
                   tableTools = list(
                     "sSwfPath" =     "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables-    tabletools/2.1.5/swf/copy_csv_xls.swf",
                     "aButtons" = list(
                       "copy",
                       "print",
                       list("sExtends" = "collection",
                            "sButtonText" = "Save",
                            "aButtons" = c("csv","xls")))),
                   ColVis = list(activate= "click", align = "right"))

  )})
```

Furthermore, when I upload a file (despite the warning including the filter option) the range slider doesn't let you to select an interval, just the different values of the rows (sorry but I cant upload a file yet :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been [fixed](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/commit/97e4b2eb0edee6226f0397d7b4f8f4220c4f0a9a) in the [current development version](https://github.com/rstudio/DT) of **DT** (>= 0.1.16). There must be a column in which all values are missing (`NA`) in your data, in which case **DT** will disable the filter since it does not make any sense to filter a full column of `NA`s.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Yihui, the warnings still appear when I run the app, but I've solved the range slider problem adding the argument "dec" in the read.table line to specify which is the the character used in the file for decimal points.